# How do I find the installed RAM layout in my MacBook without opening it up?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, upgrade, memory

I have a mid-2009 MacBook with 4 GB of RAM installed in it and I'd like to upgrade it to 8 GB of RAM. In order to do that I have to figure out what the installed RAM configuration is so I can determine what it is I need to order.

How do I see the installed RAM configuration in the MacBook without opening it up and actually looking inside?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the current RAM configuration in a visual overview by:

1. Going to the  menu
2. `About this Mac`
3. `more info`
4. `memory`

[image]

If you'd like further detail, open the `System Report...` from the `Overview` tab of `About this Mac`. This can also be accessed by holding <kbd>⌥</kbd> while the  menu is open, then selecting `System Information`.

Answer (score 0):

To see the RAM installed in your MacBook without opening it up:

1. From the Apple menu (the little Apple icon in the upper left hand corner of your main monitor), select `About This Mac`. In the window that appears the total memory installed on the machine is listed.
2. To see the details of what's installed click the `More Info...` button and in the window that opens select the `Memory` tab. This will show you which slots are filled in your MacBook and how much RAM is installed in each slot. There's also a link on this tab that will take you to instructions for upgrading the RAM in your MacBook.